# How to ignore first and last element in xpath

Tags: xpath

How to ignore first and last element in xpath? Couldnt find any example on the internet. I only found that you can use `[position()>1]` to ignore first element but how i can ignore last too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `[position()>1 and position()<last()]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
[postion() < last()]
```

(if the expression appears in an XML document, for example an XSLT stylesheet, then you'll need to escape the `<` as `&lt;`)

Comment: Yes but I want to ignore first too

Comment: @xoemab you can use more than one predicate at the same time: `someElement[position() > 1][position() < last()]`, or combine the two tests with `and`: `[position() > 1 and position() < last()]`